# Organization of Adobe Edge Animate project

Tags: adobe, adobe-edge

I have a large Edge Animate project (multiple screens) that is getting unruly to manage. We exported a symbol library, but every page that re-imports a symbol doubles the images in our /images directory.

Anyone have reference organizations for Edge?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to change the value of the 'im' variable inside '_edge.js',
and then open the project and save / publish it again. This should change the images folder
for this project.